# Table is displayed with header at the bottom

Tags: html, visual-studio

I have made a simple `HTML` page, using `Visual Studio Code`, that should display a `table`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <dt>180 cm</dt>
        <dt>70 kg</dt>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <dt>182 cm</dt>
        <dt>75 kg</dt>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I run the page using `Live Server`, I get the following display.

```
180 cm
70 kg
182 cm    
75 kg
Height  Weight
```

As you can see, the headers are at the bottom instead of the top, and the rows of the body of the table do not form columns. Please your advice.

Comment: _dt_ should be _td_

Comment: It should be <td> instead of <dt>. Learn about tables in https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table3

Comment: Thanks! Weird (and a pity) that VSC doesn't give an error warning when entering incorrect code.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the Table data (td) tag wrong. It should be td not dt.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Height</th>
    <th>Weight</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>180 cm</td>
    <td>70 kg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>182 cm</td>
    <td>75 kg</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>180 cm</td>
        <td>70 kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>182 cm</td>
        <td>75 kg</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

you don't used `<thead>` & `<tbody>`, which is the main block of table.

`<thead>` is for header of table, the columns' that show title of row.

`<tbody>` is for body of table, the place that your row added into it.

also you spell `<td>` wrong (`dt`)